# Missing required configuration "name" which has no default value when trying a kafka connect to snowflake

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-connector

I have my config/SF_connect.properties file like below

```
tasks.max=8
topics=topic1,topic2
snowflake.topic2table.map= topic1:table1,topic2:table2
buffer.count.records=10000
buffer.flush.time=60
buffer.size.bytes=5000000
snowflake.url.name=myorganization-myaccount.snowflakecomputing.com:443
snowflake.user.name=jane.smith
snowflake.private.key=xyz123
snowflake.private.key.passphrase=jkladu098jfd089adsq4r
snowflake.database.name=mydb
snowflake.schema.name=myschema
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeAvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
value.converter.basic.auth.user.info=jane.smith:MyStrongPassword
```

and get the error
`Missing required configuration "name" which has no default value when trying a kafka connect to snowflake`

The official documentation for snowflake states a name is required parameter. So I added a `name=somerandomname` in the above file. It still doesnt work.

This is the full log indicating even the private key and passphrase is not valid (need to check with admin)

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 3 error(s):
Missing required configuration "name" which has no default value.
snowflake.private.key is not valid
snowflake.private.key.passphrase is not valid
```

Need some help on the above. The official documentation link is here
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html#configuring-the-kafka-connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to follow the section "Using Key Pair Authentication & Key Rotation" in the documentation, and provide snowflake.private.key in the SF_connect.properties and public key in Snowflake to Kafka user. Ex.: alter user jsmith set rsa_public_key='MIIBIjANBgkqh...' ;

Comment: Thanks for your reply @psabela, I am fairly confident the admin who generated the key pair would have done that. Will verify the same neverthless. But any reason why the name parameter is not considered inspite of providing it.

Comment: Not certain about the name error after you added it.  Double check you added the name to the property file that is in the config folder, and not to some other copy.

Comment: @PrabhakarShanmugam That error is from Connect API directly. All Connectors require a name. Also note: `connect-distributed` is recommend with JSON defined connector definitions and you seem to be using `connect-standalone` properties files.

Comment: For future readers, please note that the answer is correct, as I checked with the devops and found that though the public private key was created, the public key was not added to the snowflake user table. Also setting the name=somevalididentifier and restarting the snowflake connector made it work. Thank you @psabela and OneCricketeer